# For which values of $a, b$ and $c \in \mathbb{R}$ does the limit $\lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)} \frac{x y}{ax^2 + bxy + cy^2}$ exist?

Tags: limits

When going from the $y$ direction, that is $x=0$ and $y \to 0$, I get $0$ for the limit and when going from $x$ direction ($y=0$ and $x \to 0$) I also get $0$ for the limit. I don't know what to do with these values and how to proceed in order to get values for $a, b$ and $c$.

Comment: What happens if you proceed along the line $y=x$? Along the curve $y=x^2$? Along $x=y^2$? Remember that we have to be able to approach $(0,0)$ via *any* path and get the same limit, not just along the axes.

Comment: Does your result hold when $c=0?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let’s note $f(x,y)= \frac{x y}{ax^2 + bxy + cy^2}$. Note that we can’t have $(a,b,c)=(0,0,0)$.

If $a=c=0$, then the limit exists and is equal to $1/b$.

For $(a,c) \neq (0,0)$, by symmetry we can suppose $a\neq 0$.

Take $y = \lambda x$

Then 
$$ f(x,\lambda x)=  \frac{x \lambda}{ax^2 + bx\lambda x + c \lambda^2 x^2}= \frac{\lambda}{a + b\lambda + c \lambda^2}$$

For $\lambda =0$, this is always equal to $0$. Then pick-up a value $\lambda$ large enough in order to have $a + b\lambda + c \lambda^2\neq 0$ and $\lambda \neq 0$. You get another limit.

**Finally, the limit exists if and only if $a=c=0$.**